# Freeing memory used by no longer needed objects in instance controlled classes in java

Tags: java, enums, instance, equals

Consider the following scenario.

You are building a class, in java, where the fundamental semantics of the class demand that no two instances of the class be equal in value unless they are in fact the same object (see instance-controlled classes in Effective Java by Joshua Bloch).  In a sense this is like a very large enum (possibly hundreds of millions of "constants") that are not known until runtime.  So, to recap, you want the class to ensure that that there are no "equal" instances on the heap.  There may be lots of references to a particular object on the heap, but no extraneous equal objects.  This can obviously be done in code but it seems to me that there is a major flaw that I have not seen addressed anywhere, including in Effective Java.  It seems to me that in order to make this guarantee the instance-controlled class must keep a reference to every instance of itself that has EVER been created at any point during program execution and can NEVER "delete" one of those objects because it can never know that there are no longer any "pointers" to that object (besides the one that it itself keeps).  In other words, if you think about this in the context of reference-counting, there will come some point in the program where the only reference to the object is the one held by the class itself (the one that says, "this was created at some point").  At that point you would like to release the memory associated with the object, but you can't because that one pointer that is left has no way of knowing that it is the last one.

***Is there a good approach to providing instance-controlled classes which can also free no-longer-needed memory?***

Update: So, I think I've found something that might help.  It turns out java has a java.lang.ref class that provides weak references.  From wikipedia: "A WeakReference is used to implement weak maps. An object that is not strongly or softly reachable, but is referenced by a weak reference is called "weakly reachable". A weakly reachable object is garbage collected in the next collection cycle. This behavior is used in the class java.util.WeakHashMap. A weak map allows the programmer to put key/value pairs in the map and not worry about the objects taking up memory when the key is no longer reachable anywhere else. Another possible application of weak references is the string intern pool. Semantically, a weak reference means "get rid of this object when nothing else references it at the next garbage collection."

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but WeakReference is your friend. Allows you to keep track of something without stopping the GC from removing the object if your WeakReference is the last reference.

Comment: Large paragraphs of text freak me out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of the special reference objects, like a [weak reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).  These were created just to support the use case you mention.

As you create an object, you search your collection of weak references to see if the object already exists; if it does, you return a regular reference to it.  If it does not, you create it and return a regular reference, and add a weak reference to it to your collection.

Your weak reference will notify you when it is not used anywhere outside of your collection; you can then remove it from your collection.  With no references any where, it can then be garbage collected.

The general concept is called a "canonicalizing cache."

The [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) class is a shortcut that does some of the plumbing for this for you.

Comment: Thanks.  This looks like exactly what I needed to know.  All the best.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what your requirements are.  You say you want hundreds of millions of entires.  This suggests that a database or NoSQL is the best way to store this.

To ensure you have no duplicates, you can keep track of referenced objects which have been retained with a WeakHashMap.